# i can't alignHeaderTitle the title of my reactnative app

Tags: css, reactjs, alignment, native, items

I'm on reactnative iOS simulation on simulator.app with vscode open, look until a few hours now what can be wrong with dat code, i tried like 10 + solutions... And still the same problem

i Try to align 'left' the title in my top bar. As simple as this.

I'm working on a fresh version, i just initialized for the project.

To be fast and clear : headerTitleAlign doesn't work on my app.

Currently my code is :

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

In this case the most part of solutions i can find is to set my headerTitleAlign over the header style :

```
 <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
**<!-- PUT MY CODE HERE -->** 
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

so i did :

```
 <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      alignHeaderTitle : 'left',
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

but dat doesn't work. I mean, my title is staying at the center.
I heard it was set per default on iOS, what can i do to modify it ?

Some parts of my test :

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerTitleAlign: 'left'},
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'left',
      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

```
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ 
    title: "Title left",
    headerTitleAlign:'left',
    headerTitleStyle: { 
        textAlign:"left", 
        flex:1 
    },

      headerStyle :{
          backgroundColor : Colors.light.tint,
        },
        headerTintColor: Colors.light.background, 
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight:'bold',
        }
}}>
```

... etcetera etcetera

So i guess its maybe outside of this part of code, maybe its set by default in !important until new versions ?

I tried the same thing on my       `<Stack.Screen name="Root"`
but still same problem.

This problem is coming from the very beginning of this video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvSUJ5lUcBw&t=1705s

Thanks a lot for ur help homies

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found the answer,
React navigation said on documentation that :
[Screen of documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U84OT.png)

Is there a hack ? ))
It totally ruin the UI of my application :D

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the headerLeft function

```
 screenOptions={{
    title: null,
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.light.tint,
    },
    headerTintColor: Colors.light.background,
    headerLeft: () => (
      <View>
        <Text
          style={{ color: Colors.light.background, fontWeight: "bold" }}
        >
          Whatsapp
        </Text>
      </View>
    ),
  }}
```